# C++/MFCからC#/WPFへドラッグアンドドロップするには

Tags: c#, c++, .net

C++/MFCのプログラムからC#/WPFのプログラムにドラッグアンドドロップでデータを渡すにはどうするのがよいでしょうか。現在以下のようなコードで、C#側で`DragEventArgs`にデータが入っているのまで確認できたのですがうまく取り出せません。C++側は既存コードなのでC#側で対応したいです。値を変換するためだけのDLLをC++/CLIで作るとよいのでしょうか？

C++のコード

```
typedef struct {
    bool isBar;
    int val;
    WCHAR name[100];
} Bar;

typedef struct {
    int val;
    TCHAR name[100];
    Bar bar[1];
} Foo;

void StartDrag(Foo foo) {
    STGMEDIUM   data;
    data.tymed = TYMED_HGLOBAL;
    data.hGlobal = (HGLOBAL)foo;
    data.pUnkForRelease = NULL;

    CLIPFORMAT f;
    f = RegisterClipboardFormat(TEXT("FOO"));

    COleDataSource *DataSource = new COleDataSource();
    DataSource->CacheData(f, &data);
    DataSource->DoDragDrop(DROPEFFECT_COPY|DROPEFFECT_MOVE);
}
```

C#のコード

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Bar
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public bool IsText;
    public int value;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
    public string name;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Foo
{
    public int value;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
    public string name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 1)]
    public Bar[] bar;
}

void OnDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("FOO"))
    {
        var fooStream = e.Data.GetData("FOO");
        // fooStreamはMemoryStream、BinaryReaderで見ると
        // C++側で設定した値が入っているのが見える

        var foo = e.Data.GetData(typeof(Foo)); // fooはnull
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.aspx) ならC#のみで実現可能かと思います。
（動作までは未確認）

```
MemoryStream ms = //...
Foo obj;

byte[] data = ms.ToArray();
if (data.Length != Marshal.SizeOf(Foo)) {
  // 受信サイズがFoo型サイズと一致しないためマーシャリング不可
  // 適切なエラー処理...
}
IntPtr rawmem = Marshall.AllocCoTaskMem(data.Length);
try {
  Marshal.Copy(data, 0, rawmem, data.Length)
  obj = (Foo)Marshal.PtrToStructure(rawmem, typeof(Foo));
} finally {
  Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(rawmem);
}
```

C++側struct `Bar`, `Foo`はそれぞれ文字列型`WCHAR`, `TCHAR`メンバを含むため、C#側structの[`StructLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx)属性に適切な`CharSet`値を明示した方が良いです。

Comment: .NET 4.5以上であれば、ジェネリック版が用意されています。
if (data.Length != Marshal.SizeOf<Foo>())
  ...
Foo obj = Marshal.PtrToStructure<Foo>(rawmem);

Comment: CharSetを設定しうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。ジェネリック版については.NET 4.5.1以降で、.NET 4.5の環境でしたので使用できませんでした。

Bar bar[1]と宣言しつつ可変長配列のポインタとして実装しているのが明らかになり結局C++側も修正しそうです :)

Comment: " Bar bar[1]と宣言しつつ可変長配列のポインタとして実装"も、C#側コードを気合を入れれば（≒煩雑で退屈なコードを書けば）なんとかなります。C++側も修正可能であれば、結局はその方がよいですねー

Comment: rawmemの値にFooとBarのサイズを足したり引いたりして`foo.bar[i] = (Bar)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(Foo));`のような感じで行けそうです。助かりました。